Retardo y problemas entre TinyMCE y código JS
Les comento mi problema. Tengo el siguiente formulario
<div class="profile-content">
<!-- Así funciona, pero con el JS no!! -->
<!-- <form action="../core/profile/content.php" name="contentForm" id="contentForm" method="POST" class="form"> -->
    <form action="" name="contentForm" id="contentForm" method="POST" class="form">
        <div class="form-column">
            <div class="form-input">
                <label>Escribe acá el contenido de tu Tarjeta</label><br>
                <textarea id="content" name="content" required autofocus>
                    <?php echo $content; ?>
                </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-button">
            <input type="submit" value="GUARDAR" class="button">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Esta es la config del TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#content',
        height: 500,
        menubar: true,
        plugins: 'link lists',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | fontfamily fontsize formatselect | ' +
        ' link | bold italic underline forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
        'alignright alignjustify lineheight | checklist bullist numlist | indent outdent | ' +
        'removeformat',
        link_default_target: '_blank',
        link_assume_external_targets: 'https',
        content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
    });
</script>

Si se fijan, el action del formulario no tiene nada porque se envía al siguiente código JS
const form = document.querySelector("#contentForm")
form.addEventListener('submit', event =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form);
    for (const value of data.values()) {
        console.log(value);
    }
    fetch("/updateContent", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        switch (data) {
            case "ok":
                (tshow("success", "¡EXITO!", "<br>Contenido actualizado correctamente", 4500),
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        location.reload();
                    }, 1500));
                break;
            case "error":
                (tshow("danger", "¡ERROR!", "<br>Error al Actualizar", 4500));
                break;
        }
    });
})

Cual es el problema? El principal problema (que solo me da en este formulario con TinyMCE) es que cuando yo doy clic a "GUARDAR" el JS no muestra el contenido sino hasta dar una segunda vez clic. Es decir, si al inicio tiene "xxx" (que viene directamente de la DB) y lo cambio por "zzz" (esto es una edición), lo que aparece, tanto en la consola como en el archivo procesador es "xxx".
Necesito dar un segundo clic, para que el cambio de x a z se vea reflejado. Solo me da en este formulario con TinyMCE. Todos los JS de otros formularios funcionan igual y tienen la misma estructura.
Si le quito el event.preventDefault(); en el código JS no funciona. Mi teoría es que el TinyMCE debe tener (quizás) otro event.preventDefault() pero al revisar el código de este, veo que tiene muchos de esos 
Otros problemas (no tan relevantes) que me da el textarea es que no respeta ni el required ni el autofocus. El required puedo validarlo luego en el PHP y retroceder si el texto va vacío, pero con eso del "retardo" no he podido hacer nada.
PD: Si proceso mi formulario con la ruta exacta del archivo (es decir, sin pasar por mi JS) el proceso de edición se hace perfecto, justo por eso tengo comentada esa línea en mi código, pero lo que hace mi JS es que hace todo sin recargar la pagina y alerta al usuario que se ha hecho el proceso con un toast bien bonito, cosa que no puedo replicar si envío el formulario directamente al archivo PHP.
Otra cosa, he visto en otros post que al quitar el required del <textarea> podría funcionar pero no, no funciona, ya he probado quitando el required y el autofocus.
Alguna idea de que pasa?? 
